# Как вернуть число

Tags: c++

Я пишу класс на плюсах который должен выполнять различные операции над рациональными числами. Само число состоит из 2 чисел (числителя и знаменателя), следовательно после выполнения операции мне надо вернуть полученные новые 2 числа. В приведенном примере я вызываю в `main` метод `a.Plus(b)`. Он считает и получает 2 числа, которые мне необходимо вернуть в `main`. Как это сделать?

```
//Функция main

    #include <iostream>
    #include "Rational.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        Rational a(12,7);
        Rational b(34,17);
        
        a.Plus(b);
       
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    
    //Файл с методами
    #include "Rational.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
        Rational::Rational(int test_p1, int test_q1) // Конструктор с параметрами
        {
            p = test_p1;
            q = test_q1;
    
            cout << "ИСХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ \nчисло = " << p << "/" << q << endl;
            return;
         
        }
        int Rational::Plus(const Rational& arg)
        {
             int p1,p2,num,denom;
            p1 = p * arg.q;
            p2 = arg.p * q;
            num = p1 + p2;
            denom = arg.q * q;
            // Получили 2 числа num и denom
    
            return //???????;
    
    
        }
    
    //Файл с объявлением методов
    #ifndef RATIONAL_H
    #define RATIONAL_H
    #include <iostream>
    
    class Rational
    {
    public:
        Rational(int test_p1, int test_q1);
        int Plus(const Rational& arg);

    private:
        int p;
        int q;
    
    
    };
    
    #endif
```

Comment: `return Rational(num, denom);`

Comment: Я попробовал `return Rational(num, denom);` , но оно выдает ошибку `Ошибка C2440 return: невозможно преобразовать "Rational" в "int"`.

Comment: `int Plus(const Rational& arg);` - здесь `int` что значит?

Comment: `int` мне тут нужен только для того, чтобы была функция возвращающая значение.

Comment: Нет, он тут нужен не для этого.

Comment: Что мне делать?

Comment: Поменяйте int на Rational (плюсом к ответу Igor)

Comment: @maestro, спасибо, заработало